# Scrolling edge appearance for regular height navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I was wondering if anyone knows how to get scrolling edge appearance to work on normal height navigation bars (not large title) like in some of Apple's own apps.
In the reminders app, you can see that the navigation bar is clear but as the table/collection view scrolls up, it animates changing the navigation bar to have a translucent background. I know I can get this behaviour using large titles but in my app, but I wanted to mimic the large title with 2 Labels stacked vertically like in the Stocks App.

I've tried the following code:

```swift
// default appearance with clear nav bar and no shadow
let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance.configureWithTransparentBackground()
appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
appearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.lightText]

// scrolled appearance with the default background
// used when there's content behind the navigation view
let appearance2 = UINavigationBarAppearance()
appearance2.configureWithDefaultBackground()
//        appearance2.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBlue
appearance2.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.lightText]

//use clear style when there's no content behind it
navigationItem.standardAppearance = appearance

//use default style when there's content behind it
navigationItem.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance2
```

You can see what I mean in the reminders app when I scroll
[Video of Reminders app scrolling navigation bar appearance behaviour](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vLLm04o7EaQMah4U8GbCPvIlRN_Buw3I/view?usp=sharing)

Here's what I have in my app, Ignore the label that appears in the navigation bar as that's changed on scrolling
[Video of Simulator scrolling](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wQh4iVTfTzvQviThPCiLDBuloVRa_85k/view?usp=sharing)

If you guys can help me, it would be very appreciated

Comment: This is the default behavior in iOS 15 - all navigation bars are transparent when scrolled to top by default.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I was initially building this with iOS 14 but got it to work with the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach is fairly straight forward according to my test. Refer my code below with a gif of the result shown below

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tv: UITableView!

    //Custom TitleView for your navigation bar
    var titleLabel: UILabel! // 1

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tv.delegate = self
        tv.dataSource = self

        title = nil // 2
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true // 2

        // Creating and setting a UILabel as the new titleView
        titleLabel = UILabel()
        titleLabel.text = "Listen Now"
        navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel // 3

        // MOST CRUCIAL
        tv.contentInset.top = -20 // 4
    }

    // MARK: UITableView delegates & datasource
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
        cell.largeContentTitle = "Hello"
        return cell
    }
}
```

1. You will need a `UILabel` to later, set this as you `navigationItem.titleView`
2. Set your `title = nil` and make sure the title is a `Large title`
3. Set your custom title (i.e. - `titleLabel` in my code) as the `titleView`
4. Which is the most crucial part is to set the `contentInset.top` of your tableView to a value you find fit. The sweet spot was around `-20` for me (Reduce this value to bring the cells closer to the navbar), but you can set different values for it. `contentInset.top` is equivalent to adding `top padding` in `CSS`, it adds spacing from the top of the `tableview` to where the **First cell** is shown

[image]

Comment: So sorry for the very late reply, got busy with work as this was for a personal project. Can confirm that this helped a lot in the process of recreating the Summary Screen's Navigation bar sub title animation in Apple's Fitness app